# Why am I getting that error when typing "else if"?

Tags: java

So I'm new in java and I just started learning and while making a very simple program to determine whether the current temperature is hot, warm or cold.
It's all OK, but when I type "else if", I get a bug and I'd like to know how to fix it and the most important thing: why am I getting this error? So I don't repeat it again.  I have already searched for an answer to my question but I have found nothing, so that's why I'm asking here. Here you can see the error I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Qg3.jpg.

```
package com.marin.src;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args){

    double temp;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce una temperatura: "); //That only means "enter a temperature"
    temp = s.nextDouble();

    if(temp > 30){
        System.out.println("Hace calor."); //That only means "it's hot"
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Hace frío."); //That only means "it's cold"
    }
    else if (temp > 25){
        System.out.println("La temperatura es normal."); //that only means "it's warm"
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: `else` ends the `if` chain and has to be the last (if there is an `else`). swap the `else` and `else if` part and this part should compile.

Comment: in what kind of case would you imagine that this case could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to write `else if` after `else` statement. Your `else` statement should be written as last condition. It's the case that executes at final if any of the above cases was not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `else if` before the `else`, because the `else` block is every
other case than the `if` condition
So you have to do:

```
if () {

} else if() {

} else {

}
```

If the `if` condition is `false`, it will check the `else if` condition and if that fails to, it will execute the `else` block

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
package com.marin.src;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args){

double temp;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Introduce una temperatura: "); //That only means "enter a temperature"
temp = s.nextDouble();

if(temp > 30){
    System.out.println("Hace calor."); //That only means "it's hot"
} else if (temp > 25){
    System.out.println("La temperatura es normal."); //that only means "it's warm"
}
else{
    System.out.println("Hace frío."); //That only means "it's cold"
}


}
}
```